# Lipschitz Condition and Optimization

Tags: optimization, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

I am reading paper on [optimization](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v51/gonzalez16a.pdf). I am trying to understand the following statement:

[image]
[image]

I would like to ask how the Ball doesnot contain the minimum of f? I would appreciate if this could be graphically shown something like following taken from Bayesian Optimization and Data Science
[image]

Comment: Do not delete and re-post questions again.

Comment: There are no guidelines that prevent any user to do so.

Comment: It is not a reasonable behavior. If everyone were to do that, all the time, the site would be useless. And we don't feel like this needs to be said to users very often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x^* \in \mathcal{X}$ be the point at which the function attains the minimum value. Then by definition, we have $f(x^*) = M$. Let us apply the Lipschitz property between $x_j$ and $x^*$. Thus, we have $|f(x_j) - f(x^*)| \leq L \| x_j - x^*\| \implies \| x_j - x^*\| \geq \dfrac{f(x_j) - f(x^*)}{L} = r_j $. Thus, the point $x^* \notin B_{r_j}(x_j)$.  More specifically, it does not lie in the interior of the ball.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why it does not lie in the interior of the ball, somehow I am unable to understand. If possible a rough sketch might help. Also does $x_j$ represent arbitrary point?

Comment: How does $ \| x_j - x^*\| \geq  r_j $ implies $x^*$ is not in the interior of the ball?

Comment: @GENIVI-LEARNER The interior of the ball is given the by equation $\|x - x_j\| < r_j$, i.e., all $x \in \mathcal{X}$ that satisfy the above inequality lie in the interior of the ball. Notice the strict inequality there. And we know that the point $x^*$ satisifes $\|x^* - x_j\| \geq r_j$. Hence it cannot satisfy the condition of being in the interior of the ball giving the required result. And $x_j$ is as mentioned in the image of the paper that you have uploaded.

Comment: Noted. I am just confused on one point. Since the paper is about optimization so we are interested in $x_j$ to be $argmin$ so wouldnt that imply that $x_j$ is approaching to $x^*$ which is the $argmin$? in the definition isnt $M$ the minima?

Comment: If I get understand correctly, you are confused because you would $x_j$ to get closer to $x^*$ and thus in some sense it should be in the ball, right? If you note that as $x_j$ get closed to $x^*$, the value of $f(x_j) - M$ also decreases, ie we are considering balls of decreasing radii. If you note that $x^*$ will be within a ball of radius $2r_j$. Thus, as $x_j$ approaches $x^*$, $x^*$ will lie in that annular region and in limit the two balls and annular all eventually go to zero and thus giving us the required limit. Does this help?

Comment: Yes thats why I was confused. Because the paper is about optimization and the idea is to find the minima, so the confusion lies the fact that they are assuming a "hypothetical minima",  and saying that for $_$ to be that minima, it must lie outside the ball! This on its own is quite confusing. I was more confused with the logic they are making plus the expression. The expression as you answered makes sense! its just the logic part which I got confused. When you mentioned "giving us the required limit" You meant the value for Lipschitz constant "L"?

Comment: shall I post new question for above?

Comment: I meant the limit $x_j$ approaching $x^*$. So $M$ is the actual minima. From what I guess is that they are constructing a sequence $x_j$ such that it eventually converges to $x^*$.  In optimisation you usually need to show two things. One that the sequences converges to $x^*$. Second is how fast it converges. For the latter one usually needs to have a lower bound on the reduction in distance to the minima using which one can upper bound the number of steps to reach desired accuracy. This ball is to achieve this lower bound which in this case is $r_j$.

Comment: I think later in the paper it will be used to determine the rate or convergence. The main idea is that it is possible to create two balls centred at $x_j$ such that a larger one contains $x^*$ while it lies out of the smaller one. The radii of both these balls go to zero. The outer ball is used to show the convergence while the inner ball is used for rate convergence. Does this help?

Comment: Yes! makes so much sense. Thanks a lot!